# need latitude and longitude in 14 digit after point (xx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx)?

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude

i want to locate the ward of Nepal. to do so i need latitude and longitude in following format 83.83313830300006 27.790428447000068

is that possible to get that much from android devices?
if possible please explain.

Comment: Well do do know how much accuracy that would be? How many mm's?

Comment: sorry, no idea. can you please tell me, how would i know that ?

Comment: Are you talking about this ?

Decimal Places  |  Aprox. Distance   
1     =>                   10 kilometers      
2     =>                   1 kilometer        
3      =>                  100 meters                 
12     =>                 0.1 micron         
13     =>                10 nanometers    
14       =>              1.0 nanometer      
15     =>                0.1 nanometer

Comment: You need a precision of one nanometer? For what? Chip manufacturing?

Comment: i need to find the ward and VDC of nepal and only that precision can distinguish that.

Comment: What is 'the ward'. And what is 'VDC of nepal'? We do not believe that you need that pecision. Anyhow that's impossible with gps.

Comment: nepal is divided into 5 development region, 14 zone and 75 district
and each district is divided into ward, vdc and municipality
it is done by nepal government

Comment: you can find detail here 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_village_development_committees_of_Nepal#Dang_Deukhuri_District

Comment: What is vdc? Have you any idea about the size of a nanometer? Especially in connection with the pieces of Nepal you are talking about?

Comment: so what you think, is that possible or not ?
how much precision android devices can give ?

Comment: Apparently you did nor read the links in the one answer to your post. Start doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Check these answers

[Get twelve digits after decimal for latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018636/get-twelve-digits-after-decimal-for-latitude-and-longitude)

https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/146257/geolocation-accuracy-only-7-decimal-places

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/how-to-measure-the-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude

Answer (score 1):

You do not need more that 7 digits after decimal point. Event 5 or 6 digits will be sufficient.

7 digit is about 1 cm (centimeter) at the equator.
For a list of coordinate precision related to number of digits after
decimal point, see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

And no it is not possible to get sensefull 14 digits after decimal point.
The source of the coordinate will not have much more accuracy than 5 digits (e.g GPS) (5 digits relate to 1,1 meters)