# Get more accurate GPS lat-lon

Tags: java, android

I am receiving 7 decimal point in lat-lon . Some time the gps accuracy is low but  data is Incorrect .

How can get I lat-lon with more than 12 decimal point from GPS using android coding ?

Comment: To get accurate location `FusedLocationProviderAPI`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15018636/7012517 refer this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPS accuracy depends on GPS signal strength, GPS sensor quality and your GPS configuration. To configure GPS for high accuracy check this android document.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html#priority